# Computing $\int_{\gamma} |z|^{-4}\ |dz|$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Let $\gamma = \rho e^{it}$ on $0 \le t \le 2\pi$ be the parameterization of the curve $|z| = \rho$.

**Goal:** Compute $\int_{\gamma} |z|^{-4}\ |dz|$.

**Edited Attempt:**

$$
\int_{\gamma} {1 \over |z|^{4}}\ |dz| = \int_0^{2 \pi} {1 \over |(\rho e^{ it})|^4 } |i\rho e^{it}|\ dt = \int_0^{2 \pi} {1 \over \rho^4 } \rho\ dt = \int_0^{2 \pi} {1 \over \rho^3}\ dt = {2 \pi \over \rho^3}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: The result should turn out real, shouldn't it?

Comment: I edited the answer to make it real.  I lost track of the modulus in the original answer.  I'm still not sure if this is correct though as I'm applying Cauchy's integral formula with a modulus in the integrand which might not be legitimate.

Comment: Wouldnt the modulus stay after cancelling? then you'll get something only dependant on $\rho$, $\frac{2 \pi}{\rho ^3}$

Comment: Do you really have the absolute value 1/(|z|^4) as the integrand? Then the  second expression is not correct. The exponential should be absent as in the third one. Now the integrand is ρ^(-3) and the integral is real: 2πρ^(-3).

Comment: I edited my answer above to incorporate the comments.  Is it now correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the computation is correct now.

More generally, if $f$ is a function such that $f\equiv c$ on a curve $\gamma$, then $\int f(z)\,|dz| = c\operatorname{length}(\gamma)$.